# Symfony: How to call private services in Bundle Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I creat a bundle and I would like use best practice with it.

So all my services are private

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html

> So unless you specifically need to access a service directly from the
>   container via $container->get(), the best-practice is to make your
>   services private. In fact, the default services.yaml configuration
>   configures all services to be private by default.

And

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default

> In Symfony core we've already done that and we made all services and 
>   aliases private, except a few selected ones, that are required at
>   bootstrap time. In fact, bootstrapping is the last and only legitimate
>   use case for using the container directly.
>
> So, should we deprecate the possibility to inject the
>   service_container entirely alongside with ContainerAware*? That's a
>   possibility that the community might consider when preparing Symfony
>   5.

I have an Trait or Abstract controller which have to use by App/Controller. The trait can call the private service with autowiring and the probleme is fix BUT
The best practice of Symfony is don't use only autowiring in Bundle:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

> Public and Reusable Bundles¶
>
> Public bundles should explicitly configure their services and not rely
>   on autowiring.

So How to inject my private service in my Trait or abstract controller. Or even in the App controller without the user having to configure are services.yml.

I hope I'm clear.

Sorry for my english. I try to improve it ;-)

Comment: Did you find your answer? If not, I could explain in code, it might be more clear.

Comment: @TomášVotruba I use the solution of Api platform each action is a services. But if the user want create a controller he can use a maker controller which use the differents services action in a trait. I do not understant, Symfony say "don't use the controller" or "don't use the container" in a third party bundle but the easyadmin bundles use it.

Comment: Action as service is the best solution IMO :) The docs might be confusing in some places, also do not take it as "the God", there are many opinionated ideas, as in every docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing a third party bundle, i.e., a bundle that will be used by other people, then you must define your services manually and also in xml. Those are the best practices.

Now, third party bundles can have public services. The article you are referencing refers to your AppBundle services, that should be private because contain your application/bussiness logic. The reason why they are private by default is because you should be using Constructor Dependency Injection to use them, so things are more easily testable.

Now, in regards to your issue, you should't be creating controllers in third party bundles: it's not good practice. Instead, use the routing to route to a service that will perform the action you need. Api Platform does that, here:

[routing.xml](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Resources/config/routing/api.xml)

[EntryPointAction.php](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/Action/EntrypointAction.php)